# Jquery Mobile Properties Carried over to Subsequent Linked Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have an HTML site that imports the Jquery mobile library because it needs some mobile-phone-like buttons and slide bars (I'm building a mobile site though). However, I found out the properties on this main homepage got carried over to the linked pages.

For example, I have this in my MAIN page: (yes, using Django here)

<
script src="{% static "jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js" %}">

This MAIN page has a link to the "Contact Us" page, and that "Contact Us" page does NOT have the above line to import the jquery mobile library. Somehow if I click that link, the property from the Jquery mobile site will be carried over to the "Contact Us" page. If I refresh the "Contact Us" page, the jquery format is gone and it's fine again.

Anyone knows why this is happening and how to prevent it?
Thank you!

Comment: You will need to hide the element when you show the page ---  https://api.jquery.com/hide/  --- and show it aging when you go back  --- http://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't think it's because of the hide and show. It's something related to the jquery mobile library got inherited by the linked pages because these linked pages are back to normal after a refresh.

Comment: add `data-ajax="false"` or `rel="external"` to _Contact Us_ link.